# Save Copy of Quote PDF outside of WHMCS

Tags: whmcs

I need to save a copy of the quote pdf from WHMCS to a location outside the WHMCS directory so that we can send a direct link to the quote pdf to the client.

This is how I want it to work.

1. We view the quote PDF inside WHMCS admin area
2. When the pdf is viewed, a copy is saved to [www.ourdomain.com/quotes/999.pdf](http://www.ourdomain.com/quotes/999.pdf)
3. Then we can send a link to the client directly to the quote at [www.ourdomain.com/quotes/999.pdf](http://www.ourdomain.com/quotes/999.pdf)

Currently, you can only view the physical quote pdf when logged in as an admin user and there is no way with any hook or includes to grab the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This can literally be done in **one line of code** inside of quotepdf.tpl inside your template folder.

This is very similar to the invoicepdf solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994866/getting-the-pdf-invoice-from-whmcs) and I tried it with the quotepdf and it worked first time!

Add this code to the bottom of the quotepdf.tpl and each time the quote pdf is viewed in admin, it will output a new version to the location defined in the path below.

```
$pdf->Output('/home/jucra/public_html/quotes/'.$quotenumber.'.pdf', 'F');
```

[image]